# HTML5/CSS section.main not working

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

Been trying to figure this out for over 2 hours. Ran it through validator etc.

Its a class assignment and I cant figure out how to get the section.main class to line up correctly.

The html and the css is listed. Im not finished with the assignment but when you look at the site its pretty obvious what I am having issues with floating the section.main class properly or something. Sorry new to this.

If its easier to see the site you can view it here. http://ddawes27.webstudentsites.com/tut04/review/rose.htm

```css
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
   Tutorial 4
   Review Assignment

   Cycle Pathology Style Sheet
   Author: Derek Dawes
   Date:   7/3/16

   Filename:         race.css
   Supporting Files: 

*/

header, article, aside, figure, figcaption, hgroup, section, nav {
 display: block;
}

* {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 
 /*outline: 1px solid red; */
}

/* BODY SECTION */


body {
 position: relative;
 width: 98%;
 min-width: 1000px;
 max-width: 1400px;
 
}

/* HEADER SECTION */

header {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: black;
 padding-bottom: 500px;
}

header img {
 width: 100%;
 
}

/* NAVIGATION SECTION */

nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

  /* HORIZONTAL NAVIGATION PANE */

nav.horizontal {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 
}

nav.horizontal li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: rgb(49, 38, 31);
 padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 85%;
}

nav.horizontal li a {
 color: white;
}

nav.horizontal li a:hover {
 color: rgb(215, 181, 151);
}

  /* VERTICAL NAVIGATION PANE */

nav.vertical li {
 font-size: 85%;
 list-style-type: none;
 
}

nav.vertical a {
 color: white;
 display: block;
 text-indent: 10px;
}

nav.vertical a:hover {
 background-color:  rgb(51, 51, 51);
 outline: 2px solid rgb(215, 181, 151);
}

li.newgroup {
 padding-top: 25px;
}

/* MAIN SECTION */

.main {
 
 
 float: left;
 margin-left: 21%;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 49%;
 outline: 2px solid red;
}

h1.main {
 color: rgb(189, 131, 82);
 font-size: 180%;
 font-weight: normal;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}

p.main {
 margin: 15px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
 <!--
      New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
      Tutorial 4
      Review Assignment

      Cycle Pathology Rose Hill Rally Page
      Author: Derek Dawes
      Date:   7/3/16

      Filename:         rose.htm
      Supporting files: alisha.png, cp_logo2.png,
                        modernizr-1.5.js, race.css, 
                        slide01.png - slide08.png
 -->

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Rose Hill Rally</title>
  <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
  <link href="race.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

 </head>

 <body>

  <header>
            <img src="cp_logo2.png" alt="Cycle Pathology" />

            <nav class="vertical">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Events Page</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Rose Hill Rally</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tour the Palisades</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Gunnison Challenge</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Steamboat Springs Rally</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Copper Triangle</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Durango Tour</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Montrose Meander</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Route Sheets &amp; Maps</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Grand Junction Bike Fest</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Off-Road Cycling</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Photo Album</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Editor</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Cycling Links</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Colorado Cycling Groups</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">U.S. Bike Federation</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tips &amp; Tricks</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">About Cycle Pathology</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

  </header>



  <nav class="horizontal">   
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members Only</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Market Place</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Message Board</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Info</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>



  <section id="main">

   <aside>
    <p>The Grand Junction Neonatal Intensive Care Unit offers comprehensive neonatal 
       diagnostic and treatment facilities for critically ill newborns. We're dedicated 
       to providing the highest quality care for all newborns, ranging from healthy 
       neonates to sick or premature newborns requiring close observation or intensive care.
    </p>
    <p>All of the neonatologists are board certified. We believe it's critical that our 
       clinicians learn about the latest advances in neonatal intensive care to
       better serve the community of Grand Junction.
    </p>
   </aside>

   <h1>Rose Hill Rally</h1>
    <p>
     The Grand Junction Neonatal ICU is proud to sponsor this
     year's Rose Hill Rally. Please join us and Cycle Pathology for the
     Century Ride, Metric Century (62 miles), or 50K (31 miles). Rest stations
     and aid stations will be spaced throughout the Century and Metric Century
     routes.
    </p>
   <ul>
    <li>Come to Grand Junction a day early. Visit historic downtown Grand Junction, 
     explore the Grand Valley, ride the Colorado National Monument, or tour 
     local wineries.
    </li>
    <li>Riders begin the course between 7:00 a.m. and 9:00 a.m. for both the Metric
     Century and the 50K distance. Pick up your ride packet at Canyon View Park 
     between 6:00 a.m. and 9:00 a.m.
    </li>
    <li>Entry fee includes rider breakfast &amp; hot lunch, Rose Hill Rally t-shirt, 
     and course map.
    </li>
    <li>Stay and enjoy your post-ride meal with music provided by the Dam Busters.
    </li>
    <li>Teams of six or more riders will receive special t-shirts. Team entry forms must 
     be received two weeks prior to the rally.
    </li>
   </ul>

  </section>



  <article>

   <hgroup>
    <h1>Ride the Century</h1>
    <h2>&mdash; Alisha Smith</h2>
   </hgroup>

   <p>While riding 100 miles in a day may sound extreme, most casual cyclists can complete 
    a century if they follow a comprehensive training routine. Your bike should be comfortable
    and fit you well. Consider having a tune-up before the ride, and carry a spare tire 
    and patch kit, tools, and a pump.
   </p>
   <p>If you're not a regular cyclist, start your training at least 12 weeks before your
    century. Hills are a great way to train for your ride, and don't forget to allow
    for recovery days after your longer rides.
   </p>
   <p>A few days prior to the ride, you should keep hydrated and cut back on caffeine and
    alcohol. On the day of your century, eat a light breakfast of high-carbohydrate foods 
    and drink lots of water. On the ride, drink water or a sports drink <em>before</em>
    you're thirsty.
   </p>
   <p>A century isn't a race, so adopt a relaxed pace that you can follow for several
    hours. Alter your position throughout your ride, getting up off the saddle,
    stretching your back, and moving your hand position. The ride goes easier if 
    you share it with a friend or two.
   </p>
   <p>Above all, <em>enjoy the ride</em>! Most centuries are designed to go through
    scenic areas of the state. Peddle on and remember to watch the scenery.
   </p>
  </article>




  <figure>
   <div>
    <img src="slide01.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide02.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide03.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide04.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide05.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide06.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide07.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide08.png" alt="" />
   </div>
   <figcaption>Pictures from Last Year's Rose Hill Rally!</figcaption>
  </figure>


 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `section#main`, an ID not a class, classes are denoted with a . prefix, ids are denoted with a # prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In style add h1 and p tage after #main

```css
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
   Tutorial 4
   Review Assignment

   Cycle Pathology Style Sheet
   Author: Derek Dawes
   Date:   7/3/16

   Filename:         race.css
   Supporting Files: 

*/

header, article, aside, figure, figcaption, hgroup, section, nav {
 display: block;
}

* {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 
 /*outline: 1px solid red; */
}

/* BODY SECTION */


body {
 position: relative;
 width: 98%;
 min-width: 1000px;
 max-width: 1400px;
 
}

/* HEADER SECTION */

header {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: black;
 padding-bottom: 500px;
}

header img {
 width: 100%;
 
}

/* NAVIGATION SECTION */

nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

  /* HORIZONTAL NAVIGATION PANE */

nav.horizontal {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 
}

nav.horizontal li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: rgb(49, 38, 31);
 padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 85%;
}

nav.horizontal li a {
 color: white;
}

nav.horizontal li a:hover {
 color: rgb(215, 181, 151);
}

  /* VERTICAL NAVIGATION PANE */

nav.vertical li {
 font-size: 85%;
 list-style-type: none;
 
}

nav.vertical a {
 color: white;
 display: block;
 text-indent: 10px;
}

nav.vertical a:hover {
 background-color:  rgb(51, 51, 51);
 outline: 2px solid rgb(215, 181, 151);
}

li.newgroup {
 padding-top: 25px;
}

/* MAIN SECTION */

#main {
 
 
 float: left;
 margin-left: 21%;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 49%;
 outline: 2px solid red;
}

#main h1 {
 color: rgb(189, 131, 82);
 font-size: 180%;
 font-weight: normal;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}

#main p {
 margin: 15px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
 <!--
      New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
      Tutorial 4
      Review Assignment

      Cycle Pathology Rose Hill Rally Page
      Author: Derek Dawes
      Date:   7/3/16

      Filename:         rose.htm
      Supporting files: alisha.png, cp_logo2.png,
                        modernizr-1.5.js, race.css, 
                        slide01.png - slide08.png
 -->

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Rose Hill Rally</title>
  <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
  <link href="race.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

 </head>

 <body>

  <header>
            <img src="cp_logo2.png" alt="Cycle Pathology" />

            <nav class="vertical">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Events Page</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Rose Hill Rally</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tour the Palisades</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Gunnison Challenge</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Steamboat Springs Rally</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Copper Triangle</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Durango Tour</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Montrose Meander</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Route Sheets &amp; Maps</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Grand Junction Bike Fest</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Off-Road Cycling</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Photo Album</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Editor</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Cycling Links</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Colorado Cycling Groups</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">U.S. Bike Federation</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tips &amp; Tricks</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">About Cycle Pathology</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

  </header>



  <nav class="horizontal">   
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members Only</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Market Place</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Message Board</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Info</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>



  <section id="main">

   <aside>
    <p>The Grand Junction Neonatal Intensive Care Unit offers comprehensive neonatal 
       diagnostic and treatment facilities for critically ill newborns. We're dedicated 
       to providing the highest quality care for all newborns, ranging from healthy 
       neonates to sick or premature newborns requiring close observation or intensive care.
    </p>
    <p>All of the neonatologists are board certified. We believe it's critical that our 
       clinicians learn about the latest advances in neonatal intensive care to
       better serve the community of Grand Junction.
    </p>
   </aside>

   <h1>Rose Hill Rally</h1>
    <p>
     The Grand Junction Neonatal ICU is proud to sponsor this
     year's Rose Hill Rally. Please join us and Cycle Pathology for the
     Century Ride, Metric Century (62 miles), or 50K (31 miles). Rest stations
     and aid stations will be spaced throughout the Century and Metric Century
     routes.
    </p>
   <ul>
    <li>Come to Grand Junction a day early. Visit historic downtown Grand Junction, 
     explore the Grand Valley, ride the Colorado National Monument, or tour 
     local wineries.
    </li>
    <li>Riders begin the course between 7:00 a.m. and 9:00 a.m. for both the Metric
     Century and the 50K distance. Pick up your ride packet at Canyon View Park 
     between 6:00 a.m. and 9:00 a.m.
    </li>
    <li>Entry fee includes rider breakfast &amp; hot lunch, Rose Hill Rally t-shirt, 
     and course map.
    </li>
    <li>Stay and enjoy your post-ride meal with music provided by the Dam Busters.
    </li>
    <li>Teams of six or more riders will receive special t-shirts. Team entry forms must 
     be received two weeks prior to the rally.
    </li>
   </ul>

  </section>



  <article>

   <hgroup>
    <h1>Ride the Century</h1>
    <h2>&mdash; Alisha Smith</h2>
   </hgroup>

   <p>While riding 100 miles in a day may sound extreme, most casual cyclists can complete 
    a century if they follow a comprehensive training routine. Your bike should be comfortable
    and fit you well. Consider having a tune-up before the ride, and carry a spare tire 
    and patch kit, tools, and a pump.
   </p>
   <p>If you're not a regular cyclist, start your training at least 12 weeks before your
    century. Hills are a great way to train for your ride, and don't forget to allow
    for recovery days after your longer rides.
   </p>
   <p>A few days prior to the ride, you should keep hydrated and cut back on caffeine and
    alcohol. On the day of your century, eat a light breakfast of high-carbohydrate foods 
    and drink lots of water. On the ride, drink water or a sports drink <em>before</em>
    you're thirsty.
   </p>
   <p>A century isn't a race, so adopt a relaxed pace that you can follow for several
    hours. Alter your position throughout your ride, getting up off the saddle,
    stretching your back, and moving your hand position. The ride goes easier if 
    you share it with a friend or two.
   </p>
   <p>Above all, <em>enjoy the ride</em>! Most centuries are designed to go through
    scenic areas of the state. Peddle on and remember to watch the scenery.
   </p>
  </article>




  <figure>
   <div>
    <img src="slide01.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide02.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide03.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide04.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide05.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide06.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide07.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide08.png" alt="" />
   </div>
   <figcaption>Pictures from Last Year's Rose Hill Rally!</figcaption>
  </figure>


 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Curious: why are you adding selectors to the css? While the problems seems the be the fact he used a `. ` instead of a `#`?

Comment: A period (".") indicates a class, and a hash ("#") indicates an ID.

Comment: I know.... See my answer.... But I'm talking about the fact that you added the `h1` selector... Aswell as the `p` selector.  Why's that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

main is an id not a class: `#main` instead of `.main`

```css
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
   Tutorial 4
   Review Assignment

   Cycle Pathology Style Sheet
   Author: Derek Dawes
   Date:   7/3/16

   Filename:         race.css
   Supporting Files: 

*/

header, article, aside, figure, figcaption, hgroup, section, nav {
 display: block;
}

* {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 
 /*outline: 1px solid red; */
}

/* BODY SECTION */


body {
 position: relative;
 width: 98%;
 min-width: 1000px;
 max-width: 1400px;
 
}

/* HEADER SECTION */

header {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: black;
 padding-bottom: 500px;
}

header img {
 width: 100%;
 
}

/* NAVIGATION SECTION */

nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

  /* HORIZONTAL NAVIGATION PANE */

nav.horizontal {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 
}

nav.horizontal li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: rgb(49, 38, 31);
 padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 85%;
}

nav.horizontal li a {
 color: white;
}

nav.horizontal li a:hover {
 color: rgb(215, 181, 151);
}

  /* VERTICAL NAVIGATION PANE */

nav.vertical li {
 font-size: 85%;
 list-style-type: none;
 
}

nav.vertical a {
 color: white;
 display: block;
 text-indent: 10px;
}

nav.vertical a:hover {
 background-color:  rgb(51, 51, 51);
 outline: 2px solid rgb(215, 181, 151);
}

li.newgroup {
 padding-top: 25px;
}

/* MAIN SECTION */

#main {
 
 
 float: left;
 margin-left: 21%;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 49%;
 outline: 2px solid red;
}

#main h1 {
 color: rgb(189, 131, 82);
 font-size: 180%;
 font-weight: normal;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}

#main p {
 margin: 15px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
 <!--
      New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
      Tutorial 4
      Review Assignment

      Cycle Pathology Rose Hill Rally Page
      Author: Derek Dawes
      Date:   7/3/16

      Filename:         rose.htm
      Supporting files: alisha.png, cp_logo2.png,
                        modernizr-1.5.js, race.css, 
                        slide01.png - slide08.png
 -->

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Rose Hill Rally</title>
  <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
  <link href="race.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

 </head>

 <body>

  <header>
            <img src="cp_logo2.png" alt="Cycle Pathology" />

            <nav class="vertical">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Events Page</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Rose Hill Rally</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tour the Palisades</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Gunnison Challenge</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Steamboat Springs Rally</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Copper Triangle</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Durango Tour</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Montrose Meander</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Route Sheets &amp; Maps</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Grand Junction Bike Fest</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Off-Road Cycling</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Photo Album</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Editor</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Cycling Links</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Colorado Cycling Groups</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">U.S. Bike Federation</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tips &amp; Tricks</a></li>

     <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">About Cycle Pathology</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

  </header>



  <nav class="horizontal">   
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members Only</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Market Place</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Message Board</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Info</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>



  <section id="main">

   <aside>
    <p>The Grand Junction Neonatal Intensive Care Unit offers comprehensive neonatal 
       diagnostic and treatment facilities for critically ill newborns. We're dedicated 
       to providing the highest quality care for all newborns, ranging from healthy 
       neonates to sick or premature newborns requiring close observation or intensive care.
    </p>
    <p>All of the neonatologists are board certified. We believe it's critical that our 
       clinicians learn about the latest advances in neonatal intensive care to
       better serve the community of Grand Junction.
    </p>
   </aside>

   <h1>Rose Hill Rally</h1>
    <p>
     The Grand Junction Neonatal ICU is proud to sponsor this
     year's Rose Hill Rally. Please join us and Cycle Pathology for the
     Century Ride, Metric Century (62 miles), or 50K (31 miles). Rest stations
     and aid stations will be spaced throughout the Century and Metric Century
     routes.
    </p>
   <ul>
    <li>Come to Grand Junction a day early. Visit historic downtown Grand Junction, 
     explore the Grand Valley, ride the Colorado National Monument, or tour 
     local wineries.
    </li>
    <li>Riders begin the course between 7:00 a.m. and 9:00 a.m. for both the Metric
     Century and the 50K distance. Pick up your ride packet at Canyon View Park 
     between 6:00 a.m. and 9:00 a.m.
    </li>
    <li>Entry fee includes rider breakfast &amp; hot lunch, Rose Hill Rally t-shirt, 
     and course map.
    </li>
    <li>Stay and enjoy your post-ride meal with music provided by the Dam Busters.
    </li>
    <li>Teams of six or more riders will receive special t-shirts. Team entry forms must 
     be received two weeks prior to the rally.
    </li>
   </ul>

  </section>



  <article>

   <hgroup>
    <h1>Ride the Century</h1>
    <h2>&mdash; Alisha Smith</h2>
   </hgroup>

   <p>While riding 100 miles in a day may sound extreme, most casual cyclists can complete 
    a century if they follow a comprehensive training routine. Your bike should be comfortable
    and fit you well. Consider having a tune-up before the ride, and carry a spare tire 
    and patch kit, tools, and a pump.
   </p>
   <p>If you're not a regular cyclist, start your training at least 12 weeks before your
    century. Hills are a great way to train for your ride, and don't forget to allow
    for recovery days after your longer rides.
   </p>
   <p>A few days prior to the ride, you should keep hydrated and cut back on caffeine and
    alcohol. On the day of your century, eat a light breakfast of high-carbohydrate foods 
    and drink lots of water. On the ride, drink water or a sports drink <em>before</em>
    you're thirsty.
   </p>
   <p>A century isn't a race, so adopt a relaxed pace that you can follow for several
    hours. Alter your position throughout your ride, getting up off the saddle,
    stretching your back, and moving your hand position. The ride goes easier if 
    you share it with a friend or two.
   </p>
   <p>Above all, <em>enjoy the ride</em>! Most centuries are designed to go through
    scenic areas of the state. Peddle on and remember to watch the scenery.
   </p>
  </article>




  <figure>
   <div>
    <img src="slide01.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide02.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide03.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide04.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide05.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide06.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide07.png" alt="" />
    <img src="slide08.png" alt="" />
   </div>
   <figcaption>Pictures from Last Year's Rose Hill Rally!</figcaption>
  </figure>


 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### id vs class

It seems like you made a simple mistake. In your css file, instead of using `.main`, use `#main`. Since at the moment, those css lines are not being looked at (unless you have a class of .main somewhere).

To further understand the difference between ids and classes, read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp) page.

Comment: Thanks you guys rock. Def gonna use the site more. Simple mistake but totally didn't even think on that level.